# prefab with children under child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have prefab which when created adds a gameobject and 6 child of it. Since I need to change pivot position.

I created a parent to the whole prefab but when I save it as prefab, it saves only the parent and the main gameobject(now his child) but not the 6 underchilds.

So I want to save all from image to the prefab, just like the left one but with parent gameobject above it.

Here is image:

[image]

So we came up that prefab is okay but my script for initializing it is wrong. I do not know why so here is the script:

```
IEnumerator spawnMobs(float waitTime)
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    Vector3 position = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere;
    position.x = transform.position.x + (Math.Abs(position.x) * size.x);
    position.y = 0.0f;
    position.z = transform.position.z + (Math.Abs(position.z) * size.z);
    position.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position);

    GameObject Temporary_Mob_Handler = Instantiate(Mob, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    spawnedMobs++;
    spawning = false;
    yield return null;
}
```

So mob spawn but only shape, there is no sphere, particle, spellemiter, ai, lightning or canvas.

Comment: If you drag the prefab into the scene, does it still only show the immediate child? Some of them don't show all the children until it's in the scene.

Comment: I see. I haven't tried to add it manually through editor and as i added it it seems that it is okay. So the problem is in my script. I will edit my question and post it there so you read it and tell me where i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subchilds are still in the prefab, it's a limitation of Unity, you can't see in the Asset window the children of children of a prefab, but they're there and will be instantiated with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Yea. I resolved it. For some reason it didn't work. When i checked my code for initializing prefabs, everything was ok. I restarted my unity and it worked like it was intended. Thanks anyway.